# Qt5 extracting audio from video

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, qt5

I have a task: user chooses a video file, I need to get an audio track from it and give an opportunity to play it with equalizer and then save this audio in mp3.

I found an [example of media player](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) in Qt. Playing video with Qt is very easy as the example has shown so I'd like to realize this task only with Qt API. The only way I know to get audio track from video is to use libAV or similar libraries. Is there an opportunity to get audio from video with Qt API? Also I haven't found the way to save an audio in a specific format with Qt. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For what it's worth, this all sounds a bit advanced for qt multimedia capabilities. The cross-platform nature of the Qt framework means these sort of features will be lagging behind the state of the art because they need to be implemented and tested on every platform.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkCh . Did I understand correctly that this answer means no and there is no way to realize it only with Qt?

Comment: I don't *think* it's possible.